# Where is magnetic potential energy coming from?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, gauss-law, electromagnetic-induction

When electric field lines interact there develops an electric potential energy.
In developing motional emf, the power(energy) we spend is equal to the power delivered by circuit. When current flows through circuit, it induces magnetic field. These field lines interact with external magnetic field. Similar to electric field lines, here magnetic field lines interact,this makes me think that energy is stored in field. But what is the source of energy?

Comment: Presumably the energy comes from the battery (or whatever) that is driving the current. But how does the loss appear in the circuit?

Comment: As current moves in ciruit energy is lost as heat....

Comment: Yes, but we can account for that. Perhaps the external magnet changes the inductance of the circuit.